# How to adjust gVim to my HiDPI display scaling on Windows 10?

Tags: gvim, microsoft-windows

Being a user of GUI editors (mostly [Sublime Text](https://www.sublimetext.com/)) and one simple CLI editor ([`nano`](https://www.nano-editor.org/)), and just having gVim (the GUI version of `vim`) installed on my Windows 10, I can't figure out how to adjust this powerful editor to my [HiDPI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pixel_density#Named_pixel_densities) (282.42 PPI eXtra High density [according to calculator](https://www.sven.de/dpi/)) display of size 15.6 inches with resolution 3840 x 2160 and scaling set on 250%?

It currently looks like this (scaled down to 40% of taken screenshot to reflect my display scaling, so it only looks blurry to you, but hopefully you get my point) - the text is so small that it is impossible to work with:

[image: gVim on HiDPI]

How to adjust gVim to my HiDPI display scaling on Windows 10?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I'm on Windows 10, update 1909, and I've resolved this by overriding high DPI settings for gVim to System(Enhanced). Setting GUI font size did not help.

Right click on gVim icon -> Properties -> Compatibility -> Change high DPI settings -> check box "Override high DPI scaling behavior" in the bottom of the dialog window and set "Scaling performed by:" to "System (Enhanced)"

Comment: Interesting that Google directed my "gvim blurry on second monitor" search here. This answer 100% solved my problem but it doesn't answer the OP's which used "blurry" in a different context.

Comment: I wonder why is this not programmatically detected and adjusted in gVim

Comment: gVim could opt into this using a manifest with the gdiScaling setting (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sbscs/application-manifests), maybe someone should send a patch.

Answer (score 11):

On Windows, the configuration file of gVim is named:

```
_vimrc
```

It is placed in the installation directory, the default being:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim
```

To edit the file you first need to launch some text editor As Administrator.

And then open the above mentioned file.

Just add something similar to this:

```
if has('gui_running')
  set guifont=Consolas:h10
endif
```

where the important parts are both:

1. The name of font, you may choose any suitable font except for the default, which is:

   Fixedsys

   as this font can only be sized to 4 or 5.
2. `h10` determines its size; in my case 10 is adequate.